# How to handle dynamic step in cucumber without AfterStep hook?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am currently using cucumber(info.cukes)-Selenium to run automation test.

Now, I have a situation where a specific step can occur at any point of the flow.
So, I have to design a cucumber scenario to verify the dynamic page in every step.

How I can implement this without AfterStep hook? (cucumber(info.cukes) won't support AfterStep hook)

Example:

Scenario: Complect the order.

```
Given: Open URL with chrome browser
When:  Login with correct ID and password
Then: Complect the details on step 1
And: Complect the details on step 2
And: Complect the details on step 3
```

My application has a dynamic page which can appear between any pages, so I need to check if the page is displayed or not in every step and the execute the specifc task when the dynamic page is displayed and then move to the next step in the scenario.

Could you please someone help me to achieve this scenario with cucumber Selenium automation.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `info.cukes` are very old versions of cucumber. Why not use any of the newer version of it using `io.cucumber`? It supports `AfterStep` and `BeforeStep` which easily solves your problem.

Comment: Actually I am using extend reports which won't support for io.cucumber. and also I am not sure if I migrate to new jar how much re-work I need to do existing scenarios. So I am looking for solution with old cucumber version(info.cukes )

Comment: Io.cucumber supports extends report in much better way and cucumber from V 4.0.0 gives you flexibility of running test in parallel

Comment: @TheSociety  Could you please provide more info of Io.cucumber supports extends report? I have tried with different cucumber-extentsreport dependency, none of them worked with io.cucumber.

Comment: Does this mystery page pop up randomly, like an overlay prompting the user to fill out a survey? Or does this overlay or interstitial page appear only under certain conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to keeping end-to-end test code DRY, page objects are almost always the answer (or at least, they're a great place to start).  Even if you had the AfterStep hook, I'd caution about adding too much implicit stuff there, it can be a real headache to follow the flow and debug, especially for others.

In your case, I could imagine a page object for the three pages in the workflow, and each one has a `clickSubmit()` method that checks for the URL of the mystery page and completes it if present.  Something like

```
public void clickSubmit() {
  click(By.className("submitButton"));

  if (driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("mysterypage")) {
      MysteryPage mysteryPage = new MysteryPage(driver);
      mysteryPage.completeForm();
      mysteryPage.clickSumbit();
  }
}
```

Admittedly, its a little strange for a method called `clickSubmit` to be doing all that, so maybe it would be better for a helper method to exist up in the test, and just be called at the end of each step.

As an afterthought, if you have real business rules around when and where this intermediate page shows up, and it's not just random, it may be worth capturing in the gherkin.  If the user really cares that it shows up here and not there, but you made the gherkin blind to its appearance so it always "just works", you could be masking off a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, I have to add a condition to check in each and every step of the test case if the mysteryPage is displayed or not? Is there any other way we can get AfterStep hook functionality in cucumber(info.cukes)?